# ASP.NET MVC server side printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

I have an MVC 4 web application which needs to print a receipt to two network printers which should be dynamically configured(I can't use `window.print()`).I wrote a little class which I call from the web app and it successfully prints a blank page. How can I make it print a web page which contains the receipt information?

```
public class ServerPrint : PrintDocument
{
    protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\\\PrintServer\\Printer01";

        base.OnBeginPrint(e);
    }
}
```

**and I call it like this:**

```
var serverPrint = new ServerPrint();
serverPrint.Print();
```

Comment: you might have better luck if you generate a PDF receipt based off from the data on the website and send that PDF to the printer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an Active Report which contains the receipt and setting the PrinterName object on the ticket like this:

```
ticketReport.Document.Printer.PrinterName = printerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a printTemplate and fill it with your form data like :

```
public ActionResult PrintData(PrintModel model)
{
FillPrintTemplate(model);
//call print method
}
```